# javascript with Trustpilot API

Tags: javascript, trustpilot

We have 10 different languages, but I cannot make it work on the Norwegian language. The other pages the trustpilot is loading fine with the below code. But I cannot change the link to which trustpilot page it should get the data from.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
        <script async="true" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="de-de" data-template-id="1234567890" data-businessunit-id="1234567890" data-style-height="130px" data-style-width="250px" data-theme="light"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I have changed id to (1234567890) and name of the company is changed to "companyname".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the language to nb-no and it worked.